# Why is Differential Power Analysis (DPA) faster than Correlation power analysis (CPA) in Execution Time?

Tags: c, time

I have implemented both DPA and CPA attacks in C. I have executed both attacks with the same number of traces and samples (5000 traces of 6000 sample points). In terms of execution time, I get that the CPA is almost 12 times SLOWER than DPA attack. I want to understand the reason. Is it because of the Pearson Coefficient computation in CPA that is much slower than a simple average and difference computation in DPA? Or is there something wrong in my program?